# Why does this method of returning the index not always work?

Tags: python, indexing

I'm practicing some stuff using the Codewars site. I don't think it is relevant to my question but--The goal of the code is to find numbers like this:
89 = 8^1 + 9^2
135 = 1^1 + 3^2 + 5^3

This code worked with nearly all test cases, but failed one test where b > 2000:

```
def sum_dig_pow(a, b):
    list = []
    for i in range (a, b + 1):
        digitlist = [int(x) for x in str(i)]
        sum = 0
        for x in digitlist:
            sum += x**(int(digitlist.index(x)) + 1)
        if sum == i:
            list.append(i)
    print list
```

Whereas this code worked for all the tests:

```
def sum_dig_pow(a, b):
    list = []
    for i in range (a, b + 1):
        digitlist = [int(x) for x in str(i)]
        sum = 0
        digicounter = 1
        for x in digitlist:
            sum += x**digicounter
            digicounter += 1
        if sum == i:
            list.append(i)
    print list
```

the only difference is that I used the a counter to return the index of x, instead of getting it with index(x).

Can someone explain why the first code didn't always work? In general, it seems I have a hard time when I need to reference the index of an item in a list like this... and end up just using a counter like I did. :/

(also, I know there are more pythonic and efficient ways of performing this task, I'm just not very good yet.)

Comment: `digicounter` keeps an accurate index. `list.index()` only finds the index of the **first** instance, so if you have digits that appear more than once, you'll get the 'wrong' index for the 2nd or higher occurrence of that digit. Better idea still: use `enumerate()` to give you the index.

Comment: Looks like I need to figure out what enumerate does. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your first function won't find numbers like `1676` or `2427` because they contain repeated digits, and `.index()` returns the *first* occurence of a list item only.

Besides, don't use `list` as a variable name, it shadows the built-in name.